# How to get the unprocessed message count from a Windows Service Bus Subscription?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, azure, servicebus, autoscaling

I'm working on a system that needs to auto scale worker processes which pull messages from a service bus topic for processing.

To do this **I need to know the number of unprocessed messages for a given subscription. How do I do that?**

I had a look at the [SubscriptionClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh144031.aspx) Class, but there doesn't appear to be a way to find the number of messages waiting to be processed.

[image]

Comment: Actually found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957339/get-message-count-for-azure-topic-subscription Apparently you have to get the "SubscriptionDescription" from a "NamespaceManager", then you can get the message count. You can't get it from the SubscriptionClient directly however.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't see your comment, my bad :)

Comment: FYI, the 'MESSAGE COUNT' includes messages dead letters and transferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `NamespaceManager` to get your `QueueDescription` or `TopicDescription` by using `GetMessage(_name_)` or `GetTopic(_name_)`. These descriptions expose the value as `MessageCount`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: FYI, MessageCount includes any messages (Dead Letter and Transferred) in the Topic\Susbcrition. Use the MessageCountDetails property to split out the counts individually. NOTE also there seems to be a bug with these counts in that they report 0 unless some recent activity on the 'queue' has occurred.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading. `TopicDescription.MessageCountDetails` will report incorrectly as @Mikee noted - got stuck on this one. Solution was to use `SubscriptionDescription` the result of  `GetSubscription(topicName, subscriptionName)` method.