# Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging vs Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus

Tags: .net, messaging, azureservicebus, .net-standard

MS has recently introduced the **Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus** namespace.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/readme.md

It is geared for the new **.net standard** framework (as if MS doesn't have enough semi-redundant code bases)

My question is, how much better could it be in terms of performance?

I can say with confidence, that the  **Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging** leaves lots to be desired, in particular when it comes to persistent receiving.

A very useful feature of the **Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging** , is the message pump, built on top of **OnMessage()** method.

The new library, doesn't have this, and needs to rebind event handlers on every receipt to keep pumping.  Definitely a step backward .

Looking for feedback from anyone who has had experience with both and can compare..

Comment: Now there seems even something newer, called `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/MigrationGuide.md

Comment: MS trying to rebrand itself at the expense of the developers

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To address your question, what .netstd library offers that was not in .netframework one:

1. [Open Source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet). The new library is fully open sourced. You can browse, step into (with the next release) without setting up symbols server, contribute, and simply review how things work.
2. The new library is truly async as oppose to what the .netframework library was.
3. Reduced amount of responsibilities and code size. For example, [`Message`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/blob/b4285e5b436f0574810c49cacdd9973e214d155c/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/Message.cs#L14) vs `BrokeredMessage`. Your data is no longer serialized by the client.
4. AMQP by default and not SBMP.
5. The new client targets [.NET Standard and Full Framework](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/blob/b4285e5b436f0574810c49cacdd9973e214d155c/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.csproj#L8).
6. Certain client aspects redesigned to provide better options (OnMessage API to provide more failure context, [plugins](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet-plugins) and [extensibility](https://www.nuget.org/packages/servicebus.attachmentplugin), [interfaces](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/tree/b4285e5b436f0574810c49cacdd9973e214d155c/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/Core) for easier testing).
7. [Fully tested](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/tree/dev/test/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.UnitTests).

Performance wise it should be on par with the old client if not better.

> A very useful feature of the Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging , is the message pump, built on top of OnMessage() method.

You still have OnMessage API, though renamed to [`RegisterMessageHandler`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/blob/b4285e5b436f0574810c49cacdd9973e214d155c/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/Core/MessageReceiver.cs#L651).

Comment: To add..  Async is awesome but I have a need to send Synchronously and Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus no longer has `client.Send()`  only `client.SendAsync()` which is a bummer. Trying to avoid using [How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously)

Comment: @ttugates there's a reason why the new client provides no synchronous API anymore. Everything it does has to do with IO. For that, synchronous APIs make no sense. As a user of the library, you can always force synchronous execution, but then you're substantially decreasing the performance.

Comment: One other difference is the apparent lack of a "send batch" method. There is a `SendAsync(IList<Message>)` but it's not clear to me that it behaves the same as the old `SendBatchAsync()` method. See current open issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/8440 (new comments even 5 days ago), old PR on archived repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/pull/539, and the original method in `Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.topicclient.sendbatchasync?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: It's the same thing. Sending a single message or a collection ends up to be the same thing invoking the broker.

Comment: Batching was never "safe" with the old client. I. That regard, the new client is no different, @gabe.