# Get message count from SubscriptionClient

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

For logging purposes, I want to get the message count of an Azure Service Bus subscription, given a subscription client. The only [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957339/how-do-you-get-the-message-count-for-azure-topic-subscription) I found use the `NamespaceManager`, but that seems a bit redundant to me since I already have a `SubscriptionClient`. Is there a way to go directly from the client to the `SubscriptionDescription`?

Fwiw, I tried using the detour via the name space manager, but I get a it throws a 401 Unauthorized error:

```
int GetMessageCount(SubscriptionClient client) {
    NameSpaceManager nsm = new NamespaceManager(client.MessagingFactory.NamespaceEndpoints.First());
    SubscriptionDescription desc = nsm.GetSubscription(client.TopicPath, client.Name); // <-- throws error
    long numMsg = desc.MessageCount;
    return numMsg;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to go directly from the client to the SubscriptionDescription?

According to [SubscriptionClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient?view=azureservicebus-4.1.1), it does not provide a direct way to get message count from a given SubscriptionClient object.

> it throws a 401 Unauthorized error

The code `client.MessagingFactory.NamespaceEndpoints.First()` returns namespace endpoint, you initialize a new instance of the **Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager** class with that service namespace URI base address, but you do not specify a credential that authorizes you to perform actions, so it returns 401 error when you do **GetSubscription** action. The following code works fine on my side, you can try it.

```
NamespaceManager nsm = new NamespaceManager(client.MessagingFactory.NamespaceEndpoints.First(), TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("{keyName}", "{SharedAccessKey}"));

var subscriptionDesc = nsm.GetSubscription(topicName, subscriptionName);

long messageCount = subscriptionDesc.MessageCount;
```

Comment: I do something similar now, see my comment in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're constructing your `NamespaceManager` with incorrect data.

```
client.MessagingFactory.NamespaceEndpoints.First()
```

returns Azure Service Bus namespace **URI**, not a connection string that is needed.

> Is there a way to go directly from the client to the SubscriptionDescription?

Not really. To get message count on an entity is a management operation that has to go through `NamespaceManager`. Client is run-time operations on messages, not management of entities. Also, you shouldn't be creating namespace manager every time. Once you have it, cache it and re-use.

Comment: Too bad. I ended up creating the NamespaceManager once and then call `GetSubscription()` every time I want to know the number of messages. The code is a bit messy, because I have to pass around the NamespaceManager.

Comment: You're not supposed to mix management operations with the messaging operations according to the library design. That is even more enforced with the new microsoft.azure.servicebus client.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too happy with my implementation, but it gets the job done. Now I understand that things can get convoluted quickly. If I'm going deeper that route, I will clean it up and separate the two concerns.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (November 2019) there is still no way to do this via `SubscriptionClient`.

Yet people offer workarounds in this topic so here is another one via `ManagementClient`:

```cs
public async static Task<long> GetSubscriptionMessageCountAsync(
    ManagementClient client,
    SubscriptionDescription subscription)
{
    var runtimeInfo = await client.GetSubscriptionRuntimeInfoAsync(
        subscription.TopicPath,
        subscription.SubscriptionName);

    return runtimeInfo.MessageCount;
}
```