# What's the equivalent of NamespaceManager.GetQueue.MessageCount in the new NET Standard Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, .net-standard

What's the equivalent of NamespaceManager in the new NET Standard Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus?

I've used WindowsAzure.ServiceBus to do things like count messages in a queue ...

```
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(SbConnectionString);
var count = namespaceManager.GetQueue(queueName).MessageCount;
```

Moving over to the new Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus .NET Standard library, but whilst it's got classes like QueueClient and TopicClient, it's not got any NamespaceManager

How can you could do message counts in the new .NET Standard library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To provide an update:

This is now implemented and available under the `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management;` namespace.

`NamespaceManager` is now called `ManagementClient` and has (roughly) the same endpoints available.

Here's the [class itself](https://github.com/azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/commit/93cad4f2e35593844b421b51bc3d89f4a8102626#diff-073c48cbeb085711a420b3e86cbaee6d) as part of the [pull request to merge it into the main repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65#issuecomment-338874419).

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The new API doesn't support reading message counts. You'd have to use Azure Monitor API to get them.

Read why that's that case and how to work with Azure Monitor in [Reading Azure Service Bus Metrics](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/reading-azure-service-bus-metrics).

Answer (score 0):

You CAN read the queue message count:

```
var managementClient = new ManagementClient(connectionString);
(await managementClient.GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsync("name")).MessageCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration;

private readonly ServiceBusAdministrationClient _serviceBusAdministrationClient;

 _serviceBusAdministrationClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);

Response<QueueRuntimeProperties> queueRuntimePropertiesAsync = await _serviceBusAdministrationClient.GetQueueRuntimePropertiesAsync(name);

 ActiveMessageCount = queueRuntimeProperties.ActiveMessageCount,
                DeadLetterMessageCount = queueRuntimeProperties.DeadLetterMessageCount,
                ScheduledMessageCount = queueRuntimeProperties.ScheduledMessageCount,
                TotalMessageCount = queueRuntimeProperties.TotalMessageCount,
```

Comment: Anyway to do this without having to grant Manage on the service bus namespace?  It opens up delete and create operations using serviceBusAdministrationClient